# Write python nested dictionary items to files

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, directory-structure, writefile

I have a nested dictionary of key, value pairs structured like this:

```
(0, {'hoovervilles': 13, 'depression.': 10, 'everyday:': 6}), (1, {'mother': 10, 'child': 9, 'daughter': 3, 'prevail': 1}), (2, {'music': 6, 'style,': 2, 'listening': 2})
```

For each item in this dictionary, I want to write out a `tsv` with the `keys` and `values`.

This writes keys, values for a single item from the dictionary:

```
csv_file = '.../frequencies_dir/2.tsv'

try:
    with open(csv_file, 'w') as f: 
        for key, value in entry.items(): 
            f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(key,entry[key])) 
except IOError:
    print("I/O error")
```

How can I write *each* item from the dictionary to a separate file (`tsv`) in a directory and name the `tsv` file based on its item number in the dictionary (e.g. `2.tsv`, `3.tsv`, etc.)

Comment: What is the outermost data structure?  Your example has `(0, {...}) (1, {...})` but that's not valid python.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you have list of tuples where first item is number and second item is a dictionary?

Answer (score 0):

Your input data is not valid in python. But, if it is something like below :

```
entry= [(0, {'hoovervilles': 13, 'depression': 10, 'everyday': 6}),
    (1, {'mother': 10, 'child': 9, 'daughter': 3, 'prevail': 1}),
    (2, {'music': 6, 'style': 2, 'listening': 2})]
```

You can write :

```
for e in entry:
    print(e[0])
    with open(os.path.join('/Users/soumyabratakole/test/', str(e[0]) + '.tsv'),'w') as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter='\t', fieldnames = e[1].keys())
        w.writeheader()
        w.writerow(e[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
entry = (0, {'hoovervilles': 13, 'depression.': 10, 'everyday:': 6}), (1, {'mother': 10, 'child': 9, 'daughter': 3, 'prevail': 1}), (2, {'music': 6, 'style,': 2, 'listening': 2});
for i in entry:
    print(i[1])
    try:
        with open(f'{i[0]}.tsv', 'w') as f:
            for key, value in i[1].items(): 
                f.write("%s\t%s\n"%(key, i[1][key]))
                break
    except IOError:
        print("I/O error")
```

So that you will get three `.tsv` files like `0.tsv`, `0.tsv` and  `2.tsv` where

`0.tsv` looks like

```
hoovervilles    13
```

And so on